# Magit: Current repository?

Tags: magit

<sub>Windows 10, Emacs 25.1 , Magit</sub>

I have many git repositories.

Does the notion of the currently selected repository exist in Magit?

Comment: Magit automatically acts upon the repository which is appropriate for the *currently selected buffer*. There is no such thing as the "currently selected repository" if you invoke a Magit command from a buffer which is *not* associated with a repository.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Magit knows what the current repository is. That means that you can, for example, have multiple status buffers, each showing the status of a certain repository. When you invoke `magit-status`, Magit will automatically show the status for the current repository, either creating a new buffer or switching to an existing buffer for that repository.

The current repository is determined by asking Git what the repository for the buffer-local value of `default-directory` is. So you can invoke a Magit command and it will always do its thing in the right repository, i.e. in the directory the current buffer "is in". Like in a shell where `git` also acts on the current repository based on the shell's working directory (`$PWD`).

If the `default-directory` is not located inside a Git repository then you will likely get an error. Some commands will instead ask about creating a new repository or switching to an existing repository.

If you need that information programmatically, then you can use the function `magit-toplevel` to get the top-level directory of the current repository's working directory. Or you can use `magit-git-dir` to get the location of the `.git` directory (which might be located outside the working tree).